# Print all nodes that are N level above all Leaf Nodes

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I need to print all the nodes that are N level above all Leaf Nodes. I tried below approach, but now I am stuck and unable to proceed. Please help. I need to code **only using Java 7** and no other versions.

For example, I have this path `1 --> 2 --> 3 --> 4`, so in this case assuming `4` is my leaf node, node `3` is 1 level above `4` and node `2` is 2 levels above leaf node `4` and node `1` is 3 levels above leaf node `4`.

Note: Please use only Java 7.

```
public class NNodeBeforeLeaf {

    static Node root;
    static class Node {
        int data;
        Node left, right;
        Node(int data){
            this.data = data;
            left=right=null;
        }
    }

    public static boolean isLeaf(Node n){
        if(n.right == null && n.left == null)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int level = 2;      // level N
        root = new Node(1);
        root.left = new Node(2);
        root.right = new Node(3);
        root.left.left = new Node(4);
        root.left.right = new Node(5);
        root.right.left = new Node(8);

        print(root, 0, level);
    }

    public static void print(Node n, int currLevel, int level){
        if(n == null){
            return;
        }
        if(!isLeaf(n)){
            print(n.left, currLevel + 1, level);
            print(n.right, currLevel + 1, level);
        }
        printNode(n, currLevel, level);
    }

    public static void printNode(Node n, int currLevel, int level){}

}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate the description a bit more, or can you share an example input and what should the output look like, or if possible can you share link to the problem. From the heading, I am not able to make out what exactly you are trying to ask.

Comment: @zenwraight what I need is to print all the nodes that are 'N' level above each leaf node. So I have the code ready to find each leaf node, but I am stuck on the point where I need to find a node which is 'N' level above my leaf node. For example, i have this path `1 --> 2 --> 3 --> 4`, so in this case assuming 4 is my leaf node, node 3 is 1 level above 4 and node 2 is 2 level above leaf node 4 and node 1 is 3 level above leaf node 4.

Comment: Got it, I have an idea in mind, it's pretty straightforward, let me post it.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-nodes-distance-k-leaf-node/
K-distance from leaf program.
You can change this for your goal, if you are interested in it.

Comment: @PospolitaNikita I have seen that program, it is for printing all nodes that are k distance from a leaf node, which can be in any direction. I only need to find nodes that are N level `above` leaf nodes.

Comment: do you want to make a singly-linked list, a doubly-linked list or a binary tree? Right now what you are making in essence is a binary tree, but the tag you added is singly-linked list. I have posted an answer the basis of a tree, but if you need a singly-linked list, please let me know, I have another piece of code in mind, if you need it.

Answer (score 2):

You have a miss in your structure to do this a Node know its child but not is parent so you need to build a structure that will give you this link : here is my proposition : i build a map that give me the parent associate to a node with method   buildParentMap this function already list all the leaf in one pass to avoid a double iteration on your tree then i use this map to go up as many time as asked on each leaf i list just before here is a snippet

be carefull this code work but there is no security if your are trying to upper that root or if the same node is present in too child (but 2 Node with the same data wont be a problem)

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class NNodeBeforeLeaf {

    static Node root;

    static class Node {
        int data;
        Node left, right;

        Node(int data) {
            this.data = data;
            left = right = null;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Node : " + data;
        }
    }

    public static boolean isLeaf(Node n) {
        if (n.right == null && n.left == null)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int level = 2; // level N
        root = new Node(1);
        root.left = new Node(2);
        root.right = new Node(3);
        root.left.left = new Node(4);
        root.left.right = new Node(5);
        root.right.left = new Node(8);

        print(root, 0, level);

        int levelToUp = 1;
        HashSet<Node> result = getUpper(levelToUp, root);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result.toArray()));
    }

    private static HashSet<Node> getUpper(int levelToUp, Node node) {
        HashMap<Node, Node> parenttMap = new HashMap<Node, Node>();
        LinkedList<Node> leafs = new LinkedList<Node>();
        buildParentMap(node, parenttMap, leafs);
        HashSet<Node> result = new HashSet<>();
        for (Node leaf : leafs) {
            result.add(getUpperLevel(leaf, levelToUp, parenttMap));
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static Node getUpperLevel(Node leaf, int i, HashMap<Node, Node> parenttMap) {
        Node tmp = leaf;
        while (i > 0) {
            i--;
            tmp = parenttMap.get(tmp);
        }
        return tmp;
    }

    private static void buildParentMap(Node root2, HashMap<Node, Node> hashMap, LinkedList<Node> leaf) {
        if (root2 == null) {
            return;
        } else if (isLeaf(root2)) {
            leaf.add(root2);
        } else {
            hashMap.put(root2.left, root2);
            buildParentMap(root2.left, hashMap, leaf);
            hashMap.put(root2.right, root2);
            buildParentMap(root2.right, hashMap, leaf);
        }
    }

    public static void print(Node n, int currLevel, int level) {
        if (n == null) {
            return;
        }
        printNode(n, currLevel, level);
        if (!isLeaf(n)) {
            print(n.left, currLevel + 1, level);
            print(n.right, currLevel + 1, level);
        }
    }

    public static void printNode(Node n, int currLevel, int level) {
        String output = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < currLevel; i++) {
            output += "\t";
        }
        System.out.println(output + n);
    }

}
```

Comment: even though I voted this up (since it was the simplest solution), you could do a breadth first search of the tree until you found the element in question and store every element visited in a queue or stack. Of course, this is assuming that the tree structure is bounded.

Comment: of course and all elements (path of the tree parenty map, leaf )could be buffered and update by a controller mecanism^^but my objectif here was more to give a simple algorithm to handle this kind of issue, This code as some limits : the recursion can be a probleme too if the tree is to deep (StackOverflowError) there is no security if one leaf is closer of root  than the number of level to up. i thought that the issue was to give the logic to handle this not a full optimized code to handle his issue

Answer (score 1):

**PLEASE READ MY COMMENT FIRST**

Since the nodes in your program store data only for the nodes below them, I couldn't really find a way of actually going up the tree ':), but I could think of this work around, basically what you can do is, **each time you need to go up by n levels you can traverse down from the root to (curLevel - n)** here is a sample program that does this (it prints all the nodes at a level which is n above the current level, i hope this is what you meant):

```
class tree{
    static class Node{
        int data;
        Node left;
        Node right;

        Node(int data){
            this.data = data;
            left = null;
            right = null;
        }
    }

    static Node root;

    public static boolean isLeaf(Node n){
        if(n.left == null && n.right == null)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public static void goDownTillLevel(Node n, int level){
        int l = level;
        if(n != null){
            if(level == 0) {
                System.out.println(n.data);
            }
            else{
                if(!isLeaf(n)){
                    goDownTillLevel(n.left, --level);
                    level = l; //since by the time the above function calls finished, level had been reduced to 0
                    goDownTillLevel(n.right, --level);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void nLevelsAbove(Node n, int curLevel, int level){
        goDownTillLevel(root, (curLevel - level - 1));
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        int curLevel = 0;
        root = new Node(1);
        curLevel++;
        root.left = new Node(2);
        root.right = new Node(2);
        curLevel++;
        root.left.left = new Node(3);
        root.left.right = new Node(3);
        root.right.left = new Node(3);
        Node n = new Node(3);
        root.right.right = n;
        curLevel++;

        nLevelsAbove(n, curLevel, 1);
    }
}
```

Though I'd like to add that if going up is one of your concerns, don't use this node structure, instead add another variable to the node, a reference to the node right above it, that way this could be made much easier and shorter.

The output of the above code is:

```
2
2
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the implementation of `public static boolean isLeaf(Node n)` is wrong, it should check only if right is **null** otherwise it is not a node, either a leaf

To get the current level of node, you can try with this code

```
int level = 0;
while(node.right != null) {
    level++;
    node = node.right;
}
System.out.println("current level node: " + level);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your structure is not able to determine the height of the current node, except when traversing from bottom to top. In order to achieve this, you have to traverse to the leafs first.

Each recursion (bottom up now) should then return it's heights. As youre not stating if your tree is a full binary tree, a node can have multiple heights depending on his children. If the heights match the desired height, the node can be printed.

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class NNodeBeforeLeaf {

    static Node root;

    static class Node {

        int data;
        Node left, right;

        Node(int data) {
            this.data = data;
            left = right = null;
        }
    }

    public static boolean isLeaf(Node n) {
        return n.right == null && n.left == null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int level = 2;      // level N
        root = new Node(1);
        root.left = new Node(2);
        root.right = new Node(3);
        root.left.left = new Node(4);
        root.left.right = new Node(5);
        root.right.left = new Node(8);

        print(root, level);
    }

    public static void print(Node n, int level) {
        traversAndPrint(n, level);
    }

    private static Set<Integer> traversAndPrint(Node n, int levelToPrint) {
        if (isLeaf(n)) return Collections.singleton(0); // We are a leaf, so we have height 0

        final Set<Integer> childrenHeights = new HashSet<>();

        // are no leaf, so we have to get the heights of our children
        if (n.right != null) childrenHeights.addAll(traversAndPrint(n.right, levelToPrint));
        if (n.left != null) childrenHeights.addAll(traversAndPrint(n.left, levelToPrint));

        assert !childrenHeights.isEmpty();

        // And increase these heights
        final Set<Integer> selfHeights = new HashSet<>();
        for (Integer childrenHeigth : childrenHeights) {
            final int selfHeight = childrenHeigth + 1;
            selfHeights.add(selfHeight);
        }

        // If we have the desired height, print
        if (selfHeights.contains(levelToPrint)) printNode(n);
        return selfHeights; // return our heights
    }

    public static void printNode(Node n) {
        // Do whatever you want
        System.out.println(n.data);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found another approach. I put all nodes in a list. For each level up I remove the leaf nodes in that list. A leaf node in the list is defined as a node with left=null and right=null or if they are not null left and right should not be in the list. After the level ups I print the now leaf nodes in the list.

```
public class NNodeBeforeLeaf {

static Node root;

static class Node {
    int data;
    Node left, right;

    Node(int data) {
        this.data = data;
        left = right = null;
    }
}

public static boolean isLeaf(Node n) {
    if ((n.right == null) && (n.left == null)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int level = 2; // level N
    root = new Node(1);
    root.left = new Node(2);
    root.right = new Node(3);
    root.left.left = new Node(4);
    root.left.right = new Node(5);
    root.right.left = new Node(8);

    printNodes(getNodesNLevelAboveLeafs(root, level));
}

public static void printNodes(List<Node> nodes) {
    for (Node n : nodes) {
        System.out.println(n.data);
    }
}

public static List<Node> getNodesNLevelAboveLeafs(Node root, int level) {
    List<Node> allNodes = listAllNodes(root);
    for (int i = 0; i < level; i++) {
        allNodes.removeAll(getLeafNodes(allNodes));
    }
    return getLeafNodes(allNodes);
}

private static List<Node> getLeafNodes(List<Node> allNodes) {
    List<Node> leafs = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Node n : allNodes) {
        if (((n.left == null) || !allNodes.contains(n.left))
                && ((n.right == null) || !allNodes.contains(n.right))) {
            leafs.add(n);
        }
    }
    return leafs;
}

private static List<Node> listAllNodes(Node node) {
    List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
    nodes.add(node);
    if (node.left != null) {
        nodes.addAll(listAllNodes(node.left));
    }
    if (node.right != null) {
        nodes.addAll(listAllNodes(node.right));
    }
    return nodes;
}

}
```